# AzureStack-Tools from GitHub fails in an Azure online Lab

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-stack

I'm working on the following online course offered by Microsoft via Edx: `Configuring and Operating Microsoft Azure Stack`

While working on an online lab (in the course) titled: `connection to azure stack using powershell`, I get the following error at the following command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://github.com/Azure/AzureStack-Tools/archive/master.zip -OutFile master.zip
```

**Error**

> Invoke-WebRequest : unable to read data from the transport connection. the connection was closed

**NOTE**:

1. I've tired it at different times in different days but still the same error
2. I'm unable to complete the lab because of this error. Hopefully some could help.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `https://github.com/Azure/AzureStack-Tools/archive/master.zip` from your browser and it should download the file for you.